# Is it possible to load a web page within a web page and have access to the html element within that page you loaded?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, applet

Here is my problem.

I am attempting to have a way to help teach people about css selectors and various html pieces by allowing them to go to a website of their choosing, selecting an html element from that site, and me displaying to them all the properties of that element. Basically show them how to generate css selectors to retrieve that element etc.

Problem is, using iframes/object tags/etc do not allow you to access the page inside from your page. So I have no way of determining when the user clicks in any buttons or anything inside the other page.

I am open to pretty much any suggestions, I have thought about Java applets, or Java web start. But I wanted some professional opinions on the topic.

Is it possible at all using only Javascript or various Javascript plug ins etc?
Is it possible using a Java applet or some variation of?

Comment: it is called Chrome Devtools and console - load the page and hit F12

Comment: Sorry Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I have a web application that is the tool for them to use. I can't require people to load up the dev tools within the browser. I need them to go to the page they want to find elements in within my web application.

Comment: Nope. Won't work unless you make a proxy with a crapload of markup. It is not feasible in my opinion. A Java Applet - wow.. ;) - really Chrome devtools do ALL of what you need, including having the console with a prompt to enter selectors

Comment: Yes a Java applet.... I am/was reaching here for some sort of solution and was afraid that might be the answer.. That it's just not feasible... Which really REALLY puts a damper on my project as a whole.

Comment: If you're up for it, you could write a web scraper and display the scraped site to your users. It becomes a bit more complex of a situation if the site is a SPA.

Comment: Yeah, the scraper was my "proxy with a crapload of markup"

Comment: @kano that actually isn't a bad idea either.. And one I had thought about a good while back and forgot until you just mentioned it.

Comment: I'll check out that Google search as well. Thanks for all the help so far. Appreciate it!

Comment: Sure thing @BrandonStout. Mr mplungjan has a rather negative mind set. Let's do our best to prove him wrong; best of luck on your project :)